# I have multiple image urls and I need to all this image into image slider in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have multiple image urls and I need to all this image into image slider in android.

For example I have two images:

[image]

[image]

and need to add these images into image slider dynamically.

Comment: nice! Now how can we help you? Please add that to your question.

Comment: Try to implement on your side...There are lots of example available , implement them...And than after u get any problem than let us know on SO

Comment: Please post what you tried

Comment: Try to use [View Pager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to implement this. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in AsyncTask's doInBackground() method

```
InputStream in = new URL(IMAGE_URL).openStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

and in onPostExecute() method set it to Image view

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

OR try this :

```
private Bitmap bmp;
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(IMAGE_URL).openStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (bmp != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

}.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to load images into a slider: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

In your layout:

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
/>
```

And Then:

```
       mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

        HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        url_maps.put("Hannibal", "http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hannibal-season-2-release-date.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Big Bang Theory", "http://tvfiles.alphacoders.com/100/hdclearart-10.png");
        url_maps.put("House of Cards", "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Game of Thrones", "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/19640/game-of-thrones-season-4-jpg.jpg");

        for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                        .putString("extra",name);

           mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
        mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.transformers);
        l.setAdapter(new TransformerAdapter(this));
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView) view).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```